# Vue 3 get scss variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I have some struggles with importing scss variable into my Vue 3 app.
I have gloabal variable defined in colors like `$some-class-danger` or `$some-class-success`.

So I would need to import only `$some-class` and add danger or success property dynamicly.

So for now I have something like:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
  @import "@/scss/variables/variables";
 
  .drop-color{
    color: $some-class-danger;
  }
</style>
```

So this works, but I need it to have v-bind(label) and looks like:

```
 <style scoped lang="scss">
      @import "@/scss/variables/variables";
     
      .drop-color{
        color: $some-class- v-bind(label);
      }
    </style>
```

but it's not working that way, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Scss is converted to Css when you build you application. Scss can't be dynamique. But you can affect dynamic style ou class with Vuejs. Have a look to this page: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Try binding your sass variables file inside vue config as in following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583615/16849180